# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types. numpy

Tags: python, matrix, casting, typeerror

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types,
and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

For the below code:
A and B are numpy matrices

```
def operations(c,A,B):
   
    result={}
    A = np.array(A).astype('float64')
    B = np.array(B).astype('float64')
    shape = A.shape

    scale = c*A.copy()
    #add = np.add(np.array(A.tolist(), dtype=float),np.array(B.tolist(), dtype=float))
    add = np.add(A,B).copy()
    difference = np.subtract(A,B).copy()

    elementwise_multiplication = "not possible"

    matrix_multiplication = "not possible"
    transpose = A.T.copy()
     
    result.update([('shape', shape),('sum', add), ('scale', scale)
                    ,('difference', difference),
                   ('elementwise_multiplication',elementwise_multiplication), 
                   ('matrix_multiplication', matrix_multiplication),
                   ('transpose', transpose)
                  ])
                  
    print(result)
    return result
```

Any help is appreciated!

I tried to type cast it to a float64 but it is not working.

Comment: Your code is working absolutly fine in my machine..What are the values u passing for your function?? whne I tried smtng like `operations(9,1,2.2)` I got outputs Without any errors

Comment: it is only happening for certain test cases. Most of them run smoothly but I cannot see the test case that throws this error

Comment: can u mention such test cases?

Comment: i am unfortunately unable to see them

Comment: @SruthiR were you able to pass the test cases with below answer?

Answer (score 0):

When the array comes from another datatype (e.g. pandas dataframes) try converting to a list first and then cast to `np.ndarray`

Try these on addition and subtraction:

```
add = np.add(np.array(A.tolist(), dtype=float),np.array(B.tolist(), dtype=float))

add = np.add(A,B).copy()

difference = np.subtract(np.array(A.tolist(), dtype=float),np.array(B.tolist(), dtype=float))

difference = np.subtract(A,B).copy()
```